# How to pass a link value from a HTML page to rest web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest, user-interface

If I have a HTML or a JSP page having list of sports like below.

Tennis
Football
Hockey
Cricket

All these 4 should be a Link. If I click on any of them it should return some details wherever clicked. For this I need to pass this sport name to a REST client which will pass this as a parameter to a rest service.

My question is how to pass the value of a link whichever clicked from HTML page to a Java application like we pass text box or check box values from HTML using the form action? Or is there any better approach, please suggest

Comment: how do you want to pass it?? through ajax??

Comment: There's nothing to do with UI design here!! If you want to post the page follow the normal method else you can follow what @IsmailKuruca has mentioned in his answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Basically you'll want to create an XHR (GET, POST etc depending on the rest client configuration) and send your data.

Here is a very crude example on the subject;

```
$('.sports').on('click', function() {
   var clickedElementText = $(this).text();
   $.ajax({
     url: "/your/endpoint/url",
     method: "POST",
     data: { 
        sportName : clickedElementText;
     },
   }).success(function( response ) {
     /* success callback */
   }).failure(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
     /* failure callback */
   });
}
```

Comment: Hi could you please provide the rough complete HTML page. I am unable to move forward. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is a good way or you can just define the element

```
<a href="/sports/detail?sportName=tennis">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But the list of sports name can be varied everytime. How can we do it in such scenarios ?

Comment: I do not know jsp very well. I assume that you can visit database and get your sports name list in your jsp file.Then you can write a Java for circle to out.print <a> element

Comment: By the way,it's not good to write too many Java code in jsp,I highly recommend you to learn Ajax!